# SQL outputs string made of HTML tags?

Tags: html, sql-server, vb.net

Hopefully this is an easy one. I have a stored procedure that checks the database for various tables to see if an item is in stock. I'm trying to reuse the same procedure and extract just a part of it to check the stock level somewhere else on-site but the output from the procedure only goes to a string.

I tried outputting this string to a textbox to see how useful it was and I ended up with this unformatted HTML code below as the string result:

```
<div class="product-column-right-location">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="product-column-right-stock">
<strong>Stock</strong></div>
<div class="product-column-right-committed">
<strong>Committed</strong></div>
<div class="product-column-right-on-order">
<strong>On Order</strong></div>
<div class="product-column-right-available"><strong>Available</strong>  </div><div class="product-column-right-location">
<a href="/contact-us.aspx" alt="Global PC Tower Junction contact information" Title="Global PC Tower Junction contact information">Tower Junction - Riccarton</a></div>
<div class="product-column-right-stock">0</div><div class="product-column-right-committed">0</div><div class="product-column-right-on-order">0</div><div class="product-column-right-available">0</div><div class="product-column-right-location"><a href="/contact-us.aspx" alt="Global PC Homebase contact information" Title="Global PC Homebase contact information" >Homebase - Shirley</a></div><div class="product-column-right-stock">0</div><div class="product-column-right-committed">0</div><div class="product-column-right-on-order">0</div><div class="product-column-right-available">0</div><div class="product-column-right-location">In-Transit</div><div class="product-column-right-stock">0</div><div class="product-column-right-committed">0</div><div class="product-column-right-on-order">0</div>

<div class="product-column-right-available">0</div>

<div class="product-column-right-location">Warehouse</div><div class="product-column-right-stock">0</div><div class="product-column-right-committed">0</div><div class="product-column-right-on-order">0</div><div class="product-column-right-available">0</div>
```

The part I'm interested in is this line

```
<div class="product-column-right-available">0</div>
```

Is an easy way to hack and slash and chop that bigass string down to just the fraction I'm interested in? Or can I easily convert the ASP code returned to a usable data table?

I've tried different requests to the SQL server to see if I can get one column instead of everything, but it's such a mess in there and I don't have enough access privileges to start cleaning it out.

Comment: There is no ASP.NET code there. That's all HTML. I recommend that you _not_ reuse this stored procedure; rather find the part that gets the data you want, and use that. If you're a real stickler for reuse, turn the common part into a function and use it in both places.

Comment: My bad on the tags, I'm very tired. I'll have another go at extracting something useful out of the SQL server. Thanks

Comment: Surely there is a way to parse the string.  Are you looking to "hack and slash and chop that bigass string down" with SQL code?  Or in your client (which is in what language)?

Comment: I'm looking at extracting the right snippet with vb.net. I've found a second (and third) procedure inside the call to the server so I was looking in the wrong place to begin with.

The procedures I've found will check either the branches (1st procedure) or the Warehouse (2nd procedure) and output their result as a string. E.G. "Out of Stock."

Comment: Problem solved, after finding the two procedures that were actually behind the call to the server I managed to get the right answers from it. It spits back three strings which I just compare using a basic If statement. Seems weird to use strings as the result for a basic stock count but maybe that's just me?

Comment: @chrishinton if your problem resolved then post your answer if possible for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, after finding the two procedures that were actually behind the call to the server I managed to get the right answers from it. The main call to the server was actually just a simple method for running these two SQL Queries.

```
SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn").ToString, "xw_GetStockLevelInOut", "productID", "Location")
SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn").ToString, "xw_GetWarehouseStockLevelInOut", "productID", "Location")
```

It gives back three strings which I just compare using a basic If statement. Seems weird to use strings as the result for a basic stock count but maybe that's just me?

E.G:

```
        Dim one As String = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn").ToString, "xw_GetStockLevelInOut", "sr08509", 4)
        Dim two As String = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn").ToString, "xw_GetWarehouseStockLevelInOut", "sr08509", 11)
        Dim three As String = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn").ToString, "xw_GetStockLevelInOut", "sr08509", 12)

        If one = "Out of Stock." And two = "Out of Stock." And three = "Out of Stock." Then
                    oos = True
                    imgStock.ImageUrl = "images/oos-call-for-availability.png"
                    imgStock.AlternateText = "This item is out of stock"
                Else
                    oos = False
                    imgStock.ImageUrl = "images/in-stock.png"
                    imgStock.AlternateText = "This item is in stock"
                End If
```

There's still a bit of tweaking about exactly where on the page to run this code to make it work independently for every product, but it's giving me the info I was looking for.